# PHP 5 oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am encountering this errir when attempting to do a merge:

```
PHP Warning:  oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

I've made sure that all values that I have in the query are bound using the oci_bind_by_name() function, and that the data is valid.

Here is my code:

```
//Sample values just to test
$col1val = 'test1';
$col2val = 'test2';
$col3val = 'test3';
$col4val = 'test4';

        $sql = "merge into tablespace.tb1 c using (select :col1val from dual) cd
                on (c.col1 = cd.col1)
                when not matched then
                    insert (c.col2, c.col1, c.col3, c.col4) 
                    values (:col2val, :col1val, :col3val, :col4val)";



        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":col1val", $col1val);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":col2val", $col2val);  
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":col3val", $col3val);          
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":col4val", $col4val);

        $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
        $result = oci_execute($stid);
                    oci_free_statement($stid);
```

I am using PHP 5 and Oracle 10g.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried renaming one of the occurrences of `:col1val` to a unique name, and adding a 5th bind?

Comment: OMG...I think I may have found the glaringly obvious problem; calling oci_bind_by_name() before oci_parse().  Let me update my script and rerun.

Comment: +1 - OP kept looking and (apparently) solved their own problem.

Comment: @BadProgrammer - Remember that Stack Overflow encourages answering your own questions ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that `oci_bind_by_name()` was being called before `oci_parse()`.  `oci_parse()` needs to be called first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how works "oci_bind_by_name", but I know that an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement under oracle will need a bind variable for each instance of the value you want to affect, for example, if you are using twice VAL1, you will still have to use 2 bind variables :1 AND :2, you can't use :1 twice.

So in your example, since ":col1val" is used twice, I would suggest you try to use a ":col5val" instead. Also, try to bind in the order of appearance of the variables in the script.

That's for my contribution :-) Keep us posted.

rgds.

Answer (score 0):

your statemt is wrong, you needed an alias for the value in cd

merge into tablespace.tb1 c using (select :col1val col1 from dual) cd
                on (c.col1 = cd.col1)
                when not matched then
                    insert (c.col2, c.col1, c.col3, c.col4) 
                    values (:col2val, :col1val, :col3val, :col4val)";